# Make plugin admin page visible to other roles

Tags: plugins, php, functions, capabilities

I have created a plugin that I want users with the role of 'Editor' to be able to see and use in their admin panel.Currently, only administrators can see and use this plugin.

I believe it has something to do with the capabilities, but I am unsure of how or where to make the necessary changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My current plugin

```
/**


* Plugin Name: Nanme
 * Plugin URI: uri
 * Description: desc
 * Version: 2.2.1
 * Author: me
 * Author URI: uri
 * Requires at least: 5.8
 * Requires PHP: 7.2
 * Text Domain: wcrb
 */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wcrb_init' );

function wcrb_init() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'wcrb', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wcrb_report_page' );

function wcrb_report_page() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'woocommerce',
        __( 'Betalingsmetoder', 'wcrb' ),
        __( 'Betalingsmetoder', 'wcrb' ),
        'manage_options',
        'payment-gateway-report',
        'wcrb_report_page_callback'
    );
}

function wcrb_report_page_callback() {
    echo "example";
}
```

This is basically my plugin. I cut out the sensitive info in there.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the code? We can't tell you where to make the change and what to do if we can't see what you did. Use the edit link under the tags to update your question so that it contains everything needed to answer it

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell , thanks for replying. I updated the question now to include some code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the submenu is registered:

```php
    add_submenu_page(
        'woocommerce',
        __( 'Betalingsmetoder', 'wcrb' ),
        __( 'Betalingsmetoder', 'wcrb' ),
        'manage_options',
        'payment-gateway-report',
        'wcrb_report_page_callback'
    );
```

You've specified that you only want it to be shown to users with the capability `manage_options`. So only administrators have that capability, so only administrators can see that page.

It's documented in the official WP docs for that function:

> `add_submenu_page( string $parent_slug, string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $callback = '', int|float $position = null ): string|false`
>
> ...
>
> #### `$capability` `string` Required
>
> The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

If you want it to show for editors and other lower level roles, you need to specify a capability that editors and other lower level roles have.